# Proof/derivation of the sum of a sequence

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Question along the lines, "Use a sum formula to derive a closed form formula"
for a section covering combination theorems
$$
\mbox{Integer function:}\quad
{\mathrm f}\left(\,n\,\right) =1 + 4 + 7 + \cdots + \left(\,3n - 2\,\right)
$$

$${\mathbf Prove}\quad\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(\,3i - 2\,\right) = {n\left(\,3n - 1\,\right) \over 2}$$

Comment: have you tried induction?

Comment: You need to change the dummy variable in the argument of the sum I.e $3n$ to $3k$ or something?

Comment: Clearly, T(n)-T(1)=3n-1 & this is multiplied by the average n/2, but I have little exposure with "combination symbol" proofs.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(3i-2)=\sum_{i=1}^n3i-\sum_{i=1}^n2\\
=3\sum_{i=1}^ni-2n$$

I have used one sum formula to complete part of the result, another formula and combining of terms will complete the answer.

Comment: Thanks, =2*nCr(n+1,2)-2n=...=n(3n-1)/2